# Video as sreensaver with xscreensaver and websreensaver

Tags: xubuntu, screensaver, xscreensaver

I wanted to use video as my screen saver.
I followed the steps from [here](https://github.com/archagy/webnuxsaver/blob/master/README.md).
I did all as mentioned but xscreensaver is showing black(blank) output. What should I do?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGTOa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup from your $HOME/.xscreensaver

I only tested it with mpv videoplayer.

Add

```
"Movies"  mpv --really-quiet --no-audio --fs            \
                                  --loop=inf --no-stop-screensaver            \
                                  --shuffle --wid=$XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW        \

                                 $HOME/path/to your/video      \n\
```

Start

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

And choose  [image: Movies]

Forgot [source](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html)